# How does Genji's Swift Strike work?

Tags: overwatch

The [description of Genji's *Swift Strike*](https://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Genji) states:

> Genji darts forward, slashing with his wakizashi and passing through foes in his path. If Genji eliminates a target, he can instantly use this ability again.

However I ([and others](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/70zvyu/they_removed_ultimate_refund_on_most_characters/dn7vpqf/)) have encountered situations where it seems that I am able to kill a Genji mid dash before he reaches me, yet am still hit by swift strike (receive damage).

**How does the damage for *Swift Strike* work?**
You would think that damage would be applied as the dashing Genji's player model collides with an enemy players hitbox. However it seems like the damage may be applied to everything in the dash path simultaneously (kind of like a hitscan line attack), with the dashing Genji being purely visual.

UPDATE: Apparently some of the questionable deaths are [related to a bug](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20759006043?page=21#post-405):

> **Tim Ford (Lead Engineer of Overwatch)**:...That's a bug with Genji's Dash itself. For a very brief period of time, it can still deal damage after Genji has died. We'll get a fix for that one, soon.

Comment: Part of what you've been encountering can be explained as network lag.

Comment: This sounds like a common server issue of "favor the shooter" where you wouldn't think two attacks can both hit, but due to latency they do. This is how you end up with getting hit by people right as they are stunned or killed.

Answer (score 1):

The damage is not applied instantaneously; it does, in fact, follow Genji as he moves.

The explanation is actually very simple, Genji's Swift Strike cannot be interrupted. You can stun Genji, move him aside, freeze him, kill him, he'll still finish the Swift Strike as if nothing had happened.

Comment: Mei's Ice Wall does stop Genji. I think it's more correct to say that _status effects_ do not halt Genji's SS, but physical objects do.

Comment: Objects do not interrupt Swift Strike. Even with an object in the way, Genji will try sliding the full distance and obviously fail.

Comment: My initial comment agrees with what you just said. Sorry if I worded it badly. I meant "halt" to mean "physically stop", not "interrupt".

Comment: Yes, Swift Strike doesn't let Genji go through walls. I didn't think that was in any doubt.